# How to retrieve a specific count of messages from Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using queuedchunks.max property to retrieve  10 messages from topic at a time, but it's returning all the available messages (more than 10).Please let me know if there is a way to retreive the required messages only.

Comment: If you post some representative code, it will be alot easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Since to consume kafka messages you need to do a while loop fetching each message one by one, why don't you just break after the number of messages you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for `max.poll.records`.

If you want to consume records less than the default number, you can manually add a counter into your application, then break the loop when seen that many messages.

Answer (score -2):

[This link](http://riccomini.name/posts/kafka/2012-10-05-kafka-consumer-memory-tuning/) might help you understand.

Please do set the value of **batch.size** as shown in [kafka-configuration](http://kafka.apache.org/configuration.html) to get 10 messages from a topic at a time.